# C# installer variables

Tags: c#, installation, boolean

So I'm making a installer program for one of my projects on C# (Windows Forms).

In the main() method there should be a check if the program is already installed. If it's installed, the uninstaller form runs. If it's not installed, it installs my program.

The question is where I should store the variable that determines if the program is installed.

My 1st option was in the registry, but it's not the best choice. The variable is a boolean.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Did you look into using MSI based installer? There is a default project template in Visual Studio for an MSI based installer. That will automatically solve this problem.

Comment: the installer the other answers suggest are the way to go. anyway if you want to store that it could be a "c:\yourProgram\reg.bin" chaging of couse C to the "windows default directory"

Comment: I will use the MSI based, if my one doesn't work, but I don't like it very much.

Comment: @user220258 so many times is not about liking is about following standards and making your program easy to mantain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry is actually a good place to store this information.  This is a very common practice for installers or programs that need to store persistent global state.

While the registry itself can't store `boolean` value directly it can store values that are easily convertible to `boolean`.  For example a `DWORD` can be evaluated as a `boolean` using the rule that 0 is `false` and anything else is `true`.

For example you could use the key `HKLM:\Software\<YourCompany>\<YourProduct>` and the name value pair `Installed` as a `DWORD`.

Comment: Important information: If you want to use the registry for storage then you need to make sure the user is logged in as an administrator or that user account control (UAC) is turned off (windows 7 or newer). You can include an application manifest to make sure your program runs as an administrator.

Comment: @drew_w I do write to the registry quite often _without_ admin permissions. As long as you stay in `HKCU` it works just fine.

Comment: @UweKeim You want to check if the application is installed no matter who is logged in. HKCU won't work for this, unfortunately.

Comment: In my case, writting to HKCU will work. So I will use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using visual studio 2012 (or newer) you should consider using [InstallShield LE](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio). Otherwise, for earlier versions of visual studio you should consider using the built in installer project. There are excellent articles about these online such as [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-creating-your-msi-installer-using-visual-studio-2008). One final option for you is to use a "ClickOnce" deployment. You can find more information about those [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX).

All of these options will handle common conditions like:

- Checking if the user is logged in as an administrator (important for windows 7)
- Check if your application is already installed
- Check if the application is missing files when it is run (repair functionality)
- Find and automatically include dependancies (which are often easy to forget about)

Some of these (ClickOnce, at least) offer web deployment options. For these reasons these are probably much better options than spinning your own solution. Hope this puts you on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: InstallShield always sucked huge for me! I'm very happy with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and [WiX#](http://www.csscript.net/wixsharp.html), though.

Comment: @UweKeim I was trying to offer free and recommended solutions. I agree that InstallShield LE isn't always perfect.